# Table view disappear when I add a gradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanted to add a gradient color background to my application. Everything perfectly work except that my tableViews have disappear and my scrollViews snap their content in their background. How can I fix this problem?

```
func createGradientLayer() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "#783CBD", alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "#BC1FFF", alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    createGradientLayer()
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at createGradientLayer() in the method viewDidLayoutSubviews(). I think it is creating a lot of gradient layers...

Comment: The problem with the scrollView has been fixed. I did it by putting the function createGradientLayer() in the function viewDidLoad(). But the problem with my tableViews persists.

Answer (score 0):

This will insert a gradient layer every time the view lays out its subviews. I think UITableView doesn't like it if you mess with its internal layer structure.

I would just assign a gradient to the `backgroundView` property of the table view. See this for more info: [Adding gradient layer to tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041519/adding-gradient-layer-to-tableview)

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you show the code you've tried?

Answer (score -1):

You maybe need to bring your table view and/or other views to the front. Try:

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: tableview)
```

Do it in `viewWillAppear()`.